# How can we sort the object array based on another object array value in node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting, object

How can we sort the object array based on another object array value, like we have an object array:

```
var _userEnd = [{"userID":554,"tEnd":6},{"userID":597,"tEnd":3},{"userID":605,"tEnd":3},{"userID":617,"tEnd":1},{"userID":553,"tEnd":1},{"userID":616,"tEnd":1},{"userID":596,"tEnd":0}]
```

In this the index 1,2,3,4,5 are having the same value of the key "tEnd" i.e., 3 and 1 so I just need to sort only those index on the basis of another object array

```
var _profsort=[{"userID":596,"score":100},{"userID":616,"score":95},{"userID":553,"score":100},{"userID":617,"score":85},{"userID":605,"score":95},{"userID":597,"score":85},{"userID":554,"score":100}]
```

Here the userID `597,605,617,553,616` are having the score value `85,95,85,100,95`

so based on score, I want to sort my first array
Output should be:

```
[{"userID":554,"tEnd":6},{"userID":605,"tEnd":3},{"userID":597,"tEnd":3},{"userID":553,"tEnd":1},{"userID":616,"tEnd":1},{"userID":617,"tEnd":1},{"userID":596,"tEnd":0}]
```

Comment: Have a look at the examples using compareFunction on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object of `score` by `userID` using `Array.reduce`. Sort by `tEnd`, and if it's equal sort by the `score` you get from the `sortObject` by the `userId`:

```js
var _userEnd = [{"userID":554,"tEnd":6},{"userID":597,"tEnd":3},{"userID":605,"tEnd":3},{"userID":617,"tEnd":1},{"userID":553,"tEnd":1},{"userID":616,"tEnd":1},{"userID":596,"tEnd":0}]

var _profsort=[{"userID":596,"score":100},{"userID":616,"score":95},{"userID":553,"score":100},{"userID":617,"score":85},{"userID":605,"score":95},{"userID":597,"score":85},{"userID":554,"score":100}]

var sortObj = _profsort.reduce((r, o) => {
  r[o.userID] = o.score;

  return r;
}, Object.create(null));

_userEnd.sort((a, b) => b.tEnd - a.tEnd || sortObj[b.userID] - sortObj[a.userID]);

console.log(_userEnd);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take the delta of `tEnd` and find the `score` and take that delta.

```js
function getScore(uID) {
    return (_profsort.find(({ userID }) => userID === uID) || { score: 0 }).score;
}

var _userEnd = [{ userID: 554, tEnd: 6 }, { userID: 597, tEnd: 3 }, { userID: 605, tEnd: 3 }, { userID: 617, tEnd: 1 }, { userID: 553, tEnd: 1 }, { userID: 616, tEnd: 1 }, { userID: 596, tEnd: 0 }],
    _profsort = [{ userID: 596, score: 100 }, { userID: 616, score: 95 }, { userID: 553, score: 100 }, { userID: 617, score: 85 }, { userID: 605, score: 95 }, { userID: 597, score: 85 }, { userID: 554, score: 100 }];
    
_userEnd.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.tEnd - a.tEnd || getScore(b.userID) - getScore(a.userID);
});

console.log(_userEnd);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sort` and `find`

```
var fnGetScore = uid => _profsort.find(s => s.userID == uid).score; //method to get the score value based on userId

var output = _userEnd.sort( (a, b) => 
        (b.tEnd - a.tEnd) || 
           fnGetScore(b.userID) - fnGetScore(b.userID)) //compare tEnd first and if they are same, compare the score value
```

**Demo**

```js
var _userEnd = [{
  "userID": 554,
  "tEnd": 6
}, {
  "userID": 597,
  "tEnd": 3
}, {
  "userID": 605,
  "tEnd": 3
}, {
  "userID": 617,
  "tEnd": 1
}, {
  "userID": 553,
  "tEnd": 1
}, {
  "userID": 616,
  "tEnd": 1
}, {
  "userID": 596,
  "tEnd": 0
}];

var _profsort = [{
  "userID": 596,
  "score": 100
}, {
  "userID": 616,
  "score": 95
}, {
  "userID": 553,
  "score": 100
}, {
  "userID": 617,
  "score": 85
}, {
  "userID": 605,
  "score": 95
}, {
  "userID": 597,
  "score": 85
}, {
  "userID": 554,
  "score": 100
}];

var fnGetScore = uid => _profsort.find(s => s.userID == uid).score;

var output = _userEnd.sort((a, b) => (b.tEnd - a.tEnd) || fnGetScore(b.userID) - fnGetScore(b.userID))

console.log(output);
```